# Hide a div using jQuery when

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items, each of which needs to show a div. Click on one, and it shows you a div with tweets in it. I've been able to successfully show the divs with jQuery. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to hide the divs when the user clicks outside of said div. I've tried fiddling around with the .not() selector, but I just can't do it. Here's my code:

```
$("#twitter-wid").click(function() {
$(".recent_tweets").fadeIn(400);
});
```

In this case, #twitter-wid is the 'li' item, and .recent_tweets is the div element that I need to show. I want it such that when the user clicks anywhere out of .recent_tweets that it should hide. I've so far tried to add:

```
$.not('.recent_tweets').click(function() {
$('.recent_tweets').hide();
});
```

But to no avail. Oh and I'm new to jQuery. Thanks!

EDIT: I wonder how Twitter does it for their little drop-down menu. Click on your username and it drops down a bunch of options. Click anywhere out and it slides up.

Comment: If you wonder how twitter does it: go read their code. There is absolutely nothing wrong with reading through code someone else wrote to see how they solved a problem. Just don't copy-pasta it unless you're allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).click(function() { //Click anywhere
  $('.recent_tweets').hide();
 });
```

//ADDED for inside click

```
$('.recent_tweets').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Comment: this would still hide the div if they clicked inside it... perhaps add a check to see if the mouse loc is inside recent_tweets?

Comment: Yep, @dpmguise is right. Now the .recent_tweets div doesn't show at all.

Comment: you can stop all propagation of the event when you click inside

Comment: this link might be useful for you http://rob-bell.net/2009/02/handling-clicks-outside-a-specified-area-in-jquery/

Comment: ^^ I think that should be useful. I'll look through that code and figure it out. Thanks, you've been of great help!

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that your code worked. The only thing I changed was in the stopPropogation block, I targetted #twitter-wid instead of .recent_tweets.

Answer (score 2):

There is [outside event jquery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/) you may want to use:

```
$(".recent_tweets").bind( "clickoutside", function(event){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that now I can't get it to show when #twitter-wid is clicked (because that's outside .recent_tweets).